# Why are videos from my camera not playing in full color on my computer?

Tags: video, troubleshooting, camera

I have a Sony Cybershot DSC-H55. Any video I download off the camera onto my computer plays back in pink and grey/blue tones, not full color, on my computer. How can I fix this?

Comment: My first thought is "is this a computer problem or a camera problem?" Have you tried downloading the files to a different computer and seeing if the problem still exists?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be

- File format not supported by the video player
- Camera is recording the video in pink and gray/blue tones.

If the video plays on the camera LCD in color then it might not be the 2nd problem.

Try playing the video on another player (try [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/))

If still the problem persists then try playing the video on another computer with [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).
(There may be a problem with your computers graphic adapter).